# inverted android video proportions

Tags: android, delphi, android-mediaplayer, firemonkey

I was trying to play a vídeo recorded on the android in the 9:16 vertical position in the component ALVideoPlayerSurface1 (Alcinoe) delphi fmx android, and it played back the height and width inverted, when delving into the problem I noticed that the android saves the file with the inverted proportions, leading to the media player also play in reverse, has anyone experienced this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mobile devices always record video in landscape orientation where width is always larger than height. This is actually how the imaging sensor is orientated. Now they also  store additional meta information in the video to tell the player if the camera was orientated vertically during recording so that it can rotate orientation of the video  accordingly. Based on the images you provided it seems that either the component you are using for video playback is not taking into account the orientation meta data from video or you have recorded the video while having orientation sensor turned off ...

Comment: ... If orientation sensor is off during recording the default Landscape orientation will be stored in video metadata or no orientation information at all. In which case the player will also consider such video as being recorded in Landscape orientation.